# i can't require tcpdf library

Tags: php, html, tcpdf

i want to use a tcpdf library in my code  . it is just a sample and i used it for test . 
i use wamp server in my laptop . my project name is "mysite" . in the project i have a folder named  : tcpdf that contain a library i just download  . and another php file : index.php which contain my main code  . just it ! 
in my browser when i type  : loclhost/mysite it give me an error that can't fins the file  : tcpdf_include . 
i am sure this is simple question but i can't handel it ! please help me. it is e emergency . 
<>

---

```
    <php> 

    /**
    * Creates an example PDF TEST document using TCPDF
    * @package com.tecnick.tcpdf
    * @abstract TCPDF - Example: Removing Header and Footer
    * @author Nicola Asuni
    * @since 2008-03-04
    **  /

    // Include the main TCPDF library (search for installation path).
    require_once('tcpdf_include.php');

    // create new PDF document 
    $pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT,        'UTF-8', false);

    // set document information
   $pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR); 
   $pdf->SetAuthor('Nicola Asuni');
   $pdf->SetTitle('TCPDF Example 002');
   $pdf->SetSubject('TCPDF Tutorial');
   $pdf->SetKeywords('TCPDF, PDF, example, test, guide');

   // remove default header/footer
   $pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
   $pdf->setPrintFooter(false);

   // set default monospaced font
   $pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

   // set margins
   $pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);

   // set auto page breaks 
   $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

   // set image scale factor
   $pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

   // set some language-dependent strings (optional)
    if (@file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php')) {
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php');
    $pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
}

// ---------------------------------------------------------

    // set font
    $pdf->SetFont('times', 'BI', 20);

    // add a page
    $pdf->AddPage();

    // set some text to print
    $txt = <<<EOD
TCPDF Example 002

Default page header and footer are disabled using setPrintHeader() and setPrintFooter() methods.
EOD;

// print a block of text using Write()
$pdf->Write(0, $txt, '', 0, 'C', true, 0, false, false, 0);

// ---------------------------------------------------------

//Close and output PDF document
$pdf->Output('example_002.pdf', 'I');

//============================================================+
// END OF FILE
//============================================================+


----------
```

Comment: what is the error shown? are all the files included?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is looking for the tcpdf_include.php file in the same folder where your index.php file es located, however you mentioned the tcpdf library is within a folder, so you need to change your rquiere statement to point to the location of the file within the tcpdf folder, for example:

```
require_once 'path/to/tcpdf_include/within/tcpdf/folder';
```

Comment: hi rdgar it is work  and i don't have any problem whit require_once . but in this line my server don't know the tcpdf class  .

Comment: Hello @mostafa, could you please post the code that is giving you the error. Were you able to required the tcpdf_include.php file without a problem?

Comment: all of my code was the code i shared up here  . the error is this  : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''); ' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in C:\wamp\www\test\index.php on line 31